# Combine names of variables (in a formula) retrieved by grep in R

Tags: r, formula

I'd like to use the output of grep directly in a formula.
In other words, I use `grep` to retrieve the variables I want to select and store them in a vector.
The cool thing would be to be able to use this vector in a formula.
As to say

```
var.to.retrieve <- grep(pattern="V", x=data)
lm(var.dep~var.to.retrieve)
```

but this doesn't work...
I've tried the solution `paste(var.to.retrieve, collapse="+")` but this doesn't work either.

EDIT
The solution could be

```
formula <- as.formula(paste(var.dep, paste(var.to.retrieve, collapse="+"), sep="~"))
```

but I cannot imagine there is no more elegant way to do it

Comment: this does not work ("Inavlid formula terms")

Comment: `fmla <- paste(var.dep, var.to.retrieve, sep = "~"); fmla <- as.fomula(fmla); lm(fmla)`.

Comment: could be useful but this takes only the first term of the grep search and not all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reformulate(var.to.retrieve, response = var.dep)` is basically this.

```r
var.dep <- "y"
var.to.retrieve <- LETTERS[1:10]
r1 <- reformulate(var.to.retrieve, response = var.dep)
r2 <- as.formula(
       paste(var.dep, 
         paste(var.to.retrieve, collapse = "+"),
          sep = "~")
      )
identical(r1,r2) ## TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var_to_retrieve <- colnames(data)[grep(pattern = "V", x = colnames(data))]
lm(formula(paste(var.dep, paste(var_to_retrieve, collapse = "+"), sep = "~")),
   data = data)
```